# How to re-render a react component after returning something in a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a react app with a method to draw some arrows among divs. **The function doesn't produce arrows right away returns the JSX but just after I manually re-render the DOM by scrolling the page or do a route change**. How can I force render the DOM after the return of the function?

```
drawArrows = () => {
        const questionsList = this.state.questionsData;
        return questionsList.map(each =>
            <Arrow
                key={each.order}
                fromSelector={`#option${each.order}`}
                fromSide={'right'}
                toSelector={`#q${each.order}`}
                toSide={'left'}
                color={'#ff6b00'}
                stroke={3}
            />
        );
    }

render (){
    return(
       ...code
       {this.drawArrows()}
    )
}
```

Comment: `this.state.questionsData` a populated array when the component first renders? I don't see any issue with *this* code.

Comment: @DrewReese yes it's a populated array. The issue is I can't put a force render method (a setState or a forceUpdate) after the render method of the function

Comment: if you map directly from this.state.questionsData instead of assigning first to questionsList ? Or directly inline ? does it work better ?

Comment: @Ivo no difference. Same result

Comment: If your state is populated then I see no reason for that `drawArrows` function ***not*** to return JSX to be rendered. Are you ***sure*** it's populated at the time? Are you doing some state mutation elsewhere in the component? Can you provide a more complete component code example? Pretty much any time you get to a point where you think you need to "force react to render" you've done something wrong.

Comment: @DrewReese The code is very huge actually. But if I console.log the array just before the return statement, it shows the entire array. And yes there are many places that changing the array with setState

Comment: Console logs can be a bit tricky as they are asynchronous in nature. Can you include a better code example? Could you also try distilling your code down to a minimal, reproducible example *running* in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that we could debug in? Often you will find that when creating a minimal example your bug/issue will become very apparent.

Comment: @DrewReese sure I'll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

you can do it easy with functional Component with useState and useEffect

```
import { useState } from 'react';
const ComponentName = () => {
const [arow, setArow] = useState();
const [questionsData, setQuestionsData] = useState([]);
const drawArrows = () => questionsData.map(each =>
    <Arrow
        key={each.order}
        fromSelector={`#option${each.order}`}
        fromSide={'right'}
        toSelector={`#q${each.order}`}
        toSide={'left'}
        color={'#ff6b00'}
        stroke={3}
    />
);
useEffect(() => {
    setArow(drawArrows())
}, [])
return (
    { arow }
)

}
```

Comment: Storing React components in component state is a sure-fire way to introduce stale enclosures, it's an anti-pattern. Store the data and generate the view from state when rendering. Also, the effect with empty dependency will run only once when the component mounts and the `questionsData` state is an empty array, so nothing will be rendered on the initial render cycle, and nothing will be rendered on any subsequent render cycles.